# What SQL Query Will Get the Desired Result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

*** Edit ***
The RDBMS is SQL Server 2012

I have a program that stores data about customers. 'Customer' is an object with some standard properties (e.g. name, sex, etc). However, I want to allow the program user to add custom properties to 'Customer' (e.g. eyecolor, height).

I have created three tables that contain the following data:

**tblCustomers**

```
customer_id | name | sex
------------+------+-----
          1 | Max  | M
          2 | Tim  | M
```

**tblProperties**

```
property_id | label
------------+------
          1 | Height  
          2 | Weight
          3 | EyeColor
```

**tblPropertyValues**

```
obj_id | prop_id | prop_value
-------+---------+-----------
     1 |       1 |         60 
     1 |       2 |         84 
     1 |       3 |      Green 
     2 |       1 |         72 
     2 |       2 |         94
```

I would like to know a query to create the following result set:

```
Customer | Property | Value
---------+----------+------
     Max | Height   |   60
     Max | Weight   |   84
     Max | EyeColor | Green
     Tim | Height   |   72
     Tim | Weight   |   94
     Tim | EyeColor | NULL
```

Comment: What are the constraints here? Esp. foreign keys, but also primary ones, unique constraints, etc. What for customers without custom properties? Should they also show up in the result?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: That's the EAV anti-pattern - check out https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/, https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway or https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/ - you should **avoid this**

Comment: @marc_s : There are valid uses of this approach. The solutions given in the articles, can't be applied, where specific attributes are not known (to be defined by the application user, not the application developer). That's a problem one should try to avoid, whenever possible, but it does happen in real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `CROSS JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` :

```
select c.name as Customer, p.label as Property, pv.prop_value
from tblCustomers c cross join
     tblProperties p left join
     tblPropertyValues pv
     on pv.obj_id = c.customer_id and pv.prop_id = p.property_id;
```

Comment: Nailed it.  I need to understand CROSS JOIN better.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want, as long as I guessed your table relations correctly.

```
SELECT c.name AS customer, p.label AS property, v.prop_value AS value
FROM tblCustomer c
INNER JOIN tblPropertyValues v ON v.obj_id = c.customer_id
INNER JOIN tblProperties p ON p.property_id = v.prop_id
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

**EDIT**: The `ORDER BY` clause I used, will not match the order of data, you've shown as expected. I'm not sure on what it's based, so I will not try to adjust.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this does not return the last column in my desired result, i.e. Tim | EyeColor | NULL

Comment: You are correct - I missed that one. The answer of Yogesh Sharma is probably the one you are looking for.